# max/min height in div with display block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for something that could adapt to the size of the div.
Indeed, the content of the div is dynamic and could take little or big place in the div.

Moreover, I am using

```
div{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
}

div.show{
    height: 100px;
}
```

I tried to add instead of `height: 100px` this but it doesn't work

```
min-height: 130px;
max-height: 200px;
```

UPDATE :

FIDDLE https://fiddle.jshell.net/hecpz17q/

Comment: Please create a minimum runnable example and describe the expected behaviour in more detail. Thanks

Comment: add a fiddle, `height:auto` which is the default should be sufficient with `max-height` and `min-height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `max-height` to your initial state and a very large `max-height` to the `show` state.

```js
$("#button").click(openD);
$("#container").click(closeD);

function openD() {
  $("#container").addClass("show");

};

function closeD() {
  $("#container").removeClass("show");

};
```

```css
#button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
#container {
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-color: #c0ffee;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.740, -0.005, 0.295, 1.010);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.740, -0.005, 0.295, 1.010);
  /* added this */
  max-height: 0px;
  
}
#container.show {
  min-height: 10px;
  max-height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">
  Click
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    Hello I am a dynamic Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil laborum, amet praesentium quod cupiditate recusandae reprehenderit magni asperiores nobis vitae nulla minima dolorem alias delectus modi aspernatur quis ut, eveniet porro.
    Fugit at ipsam aut.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what you want to do, but if you simply want to hide and show some content you could use:

```
// hide container
#container{
    display: none;
}

// show container
#container.show{
  display: block;
}
```

The height of the container is adapted to the content height.

For more details see: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: I know, but I am using angularJs and googleMapSDK and I can't use this ^^

Comment: hmm ok but you never mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

update the height and max-height properties
`#container.show {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 10px;
      max-height: 100%;
}`

JSFiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/hecpz17q/